# Bare-bones shallow serialization of ado.net entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, serialization, ado.net

I realize there are loads of questions already posted regarding serialization of ADO.Net entities, but I haven't had any luck finding one that really addresses quite what I want to do.

Basically, I need a really bare-bones, shallow JSON or plain-object representation of an ADO.Net entity.  The purpose is for change-logging; i.e. when a record is going to be changed, I want to snag a copy of its data "before" and "after", and log the change.

I don't want any of the navigation, complex or other properties to be considered; just the scalar properties of the entity.  If I miss some data that only would appear in special cases, that's fine -- just trying to do a rough log.  Ideally my final code should look something like this:

```
Employee emp = db.Employees.First();

string oldRecordJSON = MySerializer.serialize(emp);

emp.Name = "Fred";
db.saveChanges();

string newRecordJSON = MySerializer.serialize(emp);

ChangeLog.logDBChange("Employees", emp.ID, oldRecordJSON, newRecordJSON, DateTime.Now);
```

...Any quick & easy way to implement `MySerializer.serialize`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just wanting some specific properties of your employee, consider creating a basic model and serialising that.

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(new MyEmployeeModel{ // set fields here});
```

You can build this as a converter if you wish, that's how I'd do it.

I have an interface, `IConverter<TInputType, TOutputType>` from which you can create a converter to inject (or whatever you want to do) into your code.

```
public interface IEmployeeFromDatabaseToBasicEmployeeModelConverter 
     : IConverter<TheDBType, MyEmployeeModel>{}

public class EmployeeFromDatabaseToBasicEmployeeModelConverter :
                               IEmployeeFromDatabaseToBasicEmployeeModelConverter 
{
  public MyEmployeeModel Invoke(TheDBType myDbTypeObject)
  {
     return new MyEmployeeModel{
      // set properties.
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Really hoping for something that works totally generically; am on an extremely compressed timeframe for this project and just need a quick-and-dirty solution (not necessarily the "best" solution).

Comment: The converter might not be quick and dirty but the first part is. Create a class to hold the data , create an object, populate it with your data, serialize it. That's a 30 second job.

Comment: Alternatively just serialize the object that comes back from your database. You already have an Employee object I see. Just pass that to the serializer I've outlined in my answer.

Comment: Ahhhhhh.... you mean I can just pass the Entity object ("Employee" in this case) directly into the JavascriptSerializer?  Did not realize that was the case!

Comment: So it turns out that this will only work on Entities that don't have any circular relationships.  What I really need is to do the same thing as above, but skip any navigation properties.

Comment: If you have circular relationships in your code, that might be a sign that you want to look at the architecture of your system. What's your specific use case Dan ?

Comment: Department <-> Employee.  Need the navigation properties which point in both directions, which results in a cycle when JavaScriptSerializer tries to do a deep serialization.

Comment: Would doing a MemberwiseClone be of use here? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx

Comment: Not quite, as that copies references as well.  I ended up just iterating through the properties of the entity, ignoring any properties whose type was an entity object or reference, and copying the rest.  Thanks!